# JavaScript Alert Not Displaying. addEventListener HTML Form

Tags: javascript, alert

I am watching a inLearning course and attempting to follow along the code myself. However the code does not seem to be working in any browser. As I am brand new to coding I am not sure what is causing the issue.

Here is the JavsScript Code.

```
(function() {
"use strict";

var state = document.getElementById('s-state');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('cart-hplus').addEventListener('submit', estimateTotal);

    var btnEstimate = document.getElementById('btn-estimate');

    btnEstimate.disabled = true;

    state.addEventListener('change',function() {

        if (state.value === '') {
            btnEstimate.disabled = true;
        } else {
            btnEstimate.disabled = false;

        }
    });
});



function estimateTotal(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (state.value === '') {
        alert('Please choose your shipping state.');

        state.focus();
    }
}

})();
```

Instead the browser is recognizing the required field attached to the html element and displaying the built in

[image: Picture of the Element that should be affected]

Relevant HTML below.

```
<form class="cart" id="cart-hplus">

<div class="group calc">
                        <p>
                        <label for="btn-estimate">Click to estimate:</label><br>
                        <input type="submit" value="Estimate Total" id="btn-estimate">
                        <input type="text" id="txt-estimate" placeholder="$0.00">
                        </p>

                        <div id="results"></div>
                    </div>

<div class="group state">
                        <label for="s-state">State (required):</label>
                        <select id="s-state" required>
                            <option value="">- select -</option>
                            <option value="CA">California (7.5% tax)</option>
                            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am aware of the disabled part, that is a separate issue that will be worked on the next part of the file. I see how they fix that. My issue is that when i click on the estimate total submit button the JavaScript should fire an alert and then highlight the state field if something is not selected from the list.

Comment: You should include your HTML too.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Also, please provide the HTML.

Comment: is cart-hplus the form?  If not then you can also try to click event listener   `document.getElementById('btn-estimate').addEventListener('click', estimateTotal);`

Comment: You're setting `btnEstimate.disabled` when the page first loads, and not changing it when the user fills in the state field.

Comment: That code should probably be in `state.addEventListener('change')`

Comment: Where is this script placed in the document?

Comment: With the edits listed above, the Estimate total will now disable and re enabled properly. However the alert is not popping up.